# Upgrade 2.4.1 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2.4.4

Getting an error on the upgrade process due to the following.

Php 7.4 is installed ok.
composer run ok.

But, magento stays on the 2.4.1 version and when I run `bin/magento list`

I can see the error is located with Vertex module that is removed in that version.

> bin/magento list
> Magento CLI 2.4.1

Available commands:
help  Display help for a command
list  List commands

In ServiceManager.php line 622:

> Service with name "Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DbStatusCommand" could not be created. Reason: Class Vertex\Tax\Setup\Schema\Triggers\MigrateVertexInvoiceSent does not exist
> In ClassReader.php line 34:
> Class Vertex\Tax\Setup\Schema\Triggers\MigrateVertexInvoiceSent does not exist

When i search into my code the only references to Vertex i can see are under the dev/ folder...that's why I don't get why this dev folder doesn't get updated automatically nor why the CLI is still in 2.4.1 while the composer update successfully went to 2.4.4

Thanks for help

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Vertex in **dev** folder does not relate to your error.

Try to remove the **vendor** folder, composer cache:

```
rm -rf vendor
composer clear-cache
```

Then upgrade again with one of the following solutions:

Solution 1: Update the composer.json file specifically the require-dev section with what is written here
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.4-p2/composer.json

Run the following commands:

```
composer install
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Solution 2: Do the following steps:

1. STAY IN PHP 7.4
2. composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update
3. composer update
4. rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/* ; bin/magento setup:upgrade
5. composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4-p2 --no-update
6. composer update
7. CHANGE TO PHP 8.1
8. rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/* ; bin/magento setup:upgrade; bin/magento setup:di:compile; bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: It did not work; Turns out there was some redis cache in top of all that and the issue was in there. Clearing the redis cache removed the error. THough it doesn't mean your answer was wrong, but it was not where I had my issue. Thanks.